# iframe Screen grabber for Videos from YouTube or Vimeo, to create a thumb nail (jpg) image .Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, applet

ASP.Net, HTML(or HTML5) with javascript / jQuery solutions......

What I am trying to do is add a thumb preview from a screenshot ( iframe ), and URL link for a  video

On the client server side - have a field set for form, if the user has a vimeo embedded  tag

They enter it on the field set - need a button under it -"to Preview"
this opens a right hand div or popup that plays the iFrame video

Next I want to grab a Screenshot of that iFrame video

Previews underneath, image is shown, if user likes it, clicks on button - and saves the thumbnail as a jpg.

This in turn saves the thumbnail path as a URL to a database and (copy of the path) URL is placed into a ThumbNail Preview - input box  ready for the page to load the Database with other info - such as title, description... etc...

---

So far have working source using HTML5, that captures screen shoot of the video (video is stored local on the computer) and displays it underneath, click save and reloads the page with just the image (png) previewed on a blank page...

---

Any help would be great - or even ideas where to start ? Would be great...  Cheers

Comment: Why do you want to create thumbnails for videos on YouTube or Vimeo if they already can provide you with the thumbnail from any video by using their APIs or looking to the meta in the HTML of the videos?

Comment: It is for a CMS that has a link for grabbing YouTube videos and Yes this does grab the thumbnail image.  But If I add the <iframe> embedded manually then the database requires a thumbnail image - hence the description of adding a thumbnail image.   You are right might have to create lots of buttons for different API's to auto upload there content - was looking at a way to be simple - display iframe from a webform then capture it and post back to the server...  cheers sisimon

Comment: For instance, if you have the following youtube video:
www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-zBIczeRbg
Check the html code and you find in meta:
<meta property="og:image" content="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/l-zBIczeRbg/maxresdefault.jpg">

Comment: Is it possible to grab this facebook open graph from within an iframe? If so that would be great...?

Comment: I still don't understand what the iframe has to do with this. The whole explanation of your issue is quite confusing to me.